# Ruby - automatically initialize class instance variables of child classes without inheriting the value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, metaprogramming

I am looking for a solution to automatically initialize a class variable through inheritance (make it available as an accessor and initialize it to some value). But I do NOT want to inherit the value, just start with a new fresh object each time on each class.

I have been looking at `class_attributes` and thought I had found a workaround but it does not seem to be working as I thought (and even if it worked, it would most likely not do the thing I want since the same array would be used everywhere so it would behave like a @@ variable)

```rb
class AbstractClass
  class_attribute :metadata
  @metadata = [] # initialize metadata to an empty array

  def self.add_metadata(metadata)
    @metadata << metadata
  end
end

def ChildClass < AbstractClass
  add_metadata(:child_class1)
end

def ChildClass2 < AbstractClass
  add_metadata(:child_class2)
end
```

I'd like to have the following :

```rb
AbstractClass.metadata # Don't really care about this one
ChildClass1.metadata # => [:child_class1]
ChildClass2.metadata # => [:child_class2]
```

I can think of a way to do this using modules with AS::Support

```
module InitializeClassInstanceVars
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern 

  included do 
    class_attribute :metadata
    self.metadata = []
  end
end
```

...and include this module in every nested class (and I believe this is what mongoid actually does for instance)

but I was hoping I could do this directly via inheritance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to initialize the class variable when it is being inherited. The Ruby style is to return and assign default value when the variable has not been set and is being accessed for the first time.

Just create another class method for that:

```
class AbstractClass
  def self.metadata
    @metadata ||= []
  end

  def self.add_metadata(metadata)
    self.metadata << metadata
  end
end

class ChildClass1 < AbstractClass
  add_metadata(:child_class1)
end

class ChildClass2 < AbstractClass
  add_metadata(:child_class2)
end

AbstractClass.metadata # => []
ChildClass1.metadata # => [:child_class1]
ChildClass2.metadata # => [:child_class2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Hooks are a great idea, you're just working off of the wrong one :) If you want to run code every time something *inherits* your class, then `inherited` is the one to use:

```
class AbstractClass
  class << self
    attr_accessor :metadata

    def inherited(child)
      child.instance_variable_set(:@metadata, [child.name])
    end
  end
end

class ChildClass1 < AbstractClass; end
class ChildClass2 < AbstractClass; end

ChildClass1.metadata
# => ["ChildClass1"]
ChildClass2.metadata
# => ["ChildClass2"]
```

Given that the question is tagged [rails](/questions/tagged/rails), you should also have `String#underscore` available; replace `child.name` with `child.name.underscore.to_s` to get `[:child_class1]`.

EDIT: I might have misunderstood the question. If you just want to start with an empty array that you can add to, chumakoff's answer is simpler.